# Error: EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW 2.79b Win10 with convert modifier particles to objects higher than 10K

Tags: error

**For the first Thank YOU all for Blender !!!**

I have a problem :

***Error: EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW***

Config: 2.79b  Win10 when using convert modifier particles to objects higher than 10K BLENDER have a crash w/o any messages, Ubuntu it's all ok w/o any problem.  **how can resolve?**

```
PS C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender> blender
Read prefs: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python
measureit: Imported multifiles
archimesh: Imported multifiles
Starting App Manager server (port 8668)
Read blend: D:\3D_blender\z.blend
Error: EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW
PS C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>
```

TNX,
Denis

Comment: `blender --help` provides a number of start up options.  Try the Debug options (eg `blender -d` )

Comment: OBvert.011
 OBvert.010
 OBvert.009
 OBvert.008
 OBvert.007
 OBvert.006
 OBvert.005
 OBvert.004
 OBvert.003
 OBvert.002
 OBvert.001
 OBHand
 OBRing-Flowers1
 OBvert
Error: EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW